# When downloading a zip of multiple files from Google Drive web page those ending in .anythingDoc are treated as if .doc files

Tags: google-drive

I know that this is a download problem since I can download individual files and there is no problem. When I select multiple files the Convert and Download says As Is for Other file types and lists the correct number of files. However the zip file contains files with the suffix .SchDoc.doc.

The files in question are schematic files created by Altium, a CAD software package. These aren't Microsoft Word .doc files.

I can't use the sync client since these are files that are Shared With Me, not My Files.

Comment: A similar problem was reported at https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/qZOCSZJ0MrY for SolidWorks files (.SLDASM, .SLDPRT, .SLDDRW).

Comment: Is the problem limited to the filename extension? Can you just rename the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Jerry101, renaming the files is sufficient. Copying or renaming from .SchDoc.doc to .SchDoc worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this in CMD.exe:

cd your_folder

ren *.SLDPRT.doc *.